# How to Load an .aspx page in Div with jQuery in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, load, external

I have an `.aspx page` with Vertical `Menus` on left containing `div`. and `clicking` on Left i want to show the content of `ExternalPage.aspx` in a `div` on right side of `div`. I have `loaded` the content of a `ExternalPage.aspx` in my home page this works fine. but, when i click on `search button` of `ExternalPage.aspx` it `Redirects` me to the `ExternalPage.aspx` and then it displays result.

**Markup:**

```
  <div id="divExternalPage">
  </div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function LoadPage() {
   $.get('http://mywebsite/ExternalPage.aspx', function(data) {
       $('#divExternalPage').html(data);
   });
}
```

**NOTE:** 
*I don't want to use iframe.*

**How to Prevent this `Redirect`to `ExternalPage.aspx`** and show the results in the same `div` where it has being loaded i.e in `divExnternalPage` ?

Comment: Send the ajax call on the search button instead of postback

Comment: `search button` Have you bound  any event to it?

Comment: Hi @Jai! in ExternalPage.aspx the Search button have a server side event which searches from DB and displays results.

Comment: @shekharshete as suggested by Adil in above comment is the way to go.

Comment: This is (more or less) impossible. In your case the result of `ExternalPage.aspx` is part of your existsting page. Any `<a href="...">` or a script like `windows.location = ...` in the `ExternalPage.aspx` content load a new page and replace your existing page. The only way to resolve this problem is to parse the result of `ExternalPage.aspx` and replace all links and every Javascript code that could load a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with some ajax call:

```
$('#divExternalPage').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.get('http://mywebsite/ExternalPage.aspx', function(data) {
     console.log(data); // this would show you the returned data.
   });
});
```

*In the browser's console you can see the response returned from your ajax request.*

---

As your content is dynamic then you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent, which is in your case is `#divExternalPage` or your can directly delegate the event to the `$(document) or $(document.body)`.

Comment: this what i have done with. but the issue is when i click search button in ExternalPage.aspx it redirects me to ExternalPage.aspx and then it displays results by using iframe it wont redirect me to the page and it behaves properly. But, unfortunately i dont want to use iframe.! any other solution?

Comment: Have you used `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior of submit button?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE! I'm updating the code below on CodeProject.com. Please search for "Loading ASPX pages into another page".**

I'm trying to do something similar: trying to load the content of an ASPX page into a HTML page and using the code behind of the ASPX page when submitting something. Maybe the code below can help you. Beware I'm just an beginner at JQuery! If someone can improve the below code... Please do!

**Demo.htm**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/LiQuickBootstrapper.js"></script>

<div id="portalViewContent" class="portalViewContent">

</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadPage('/Widget/PostCodeCheck.aspx', 'portalViewContent', 'contentWidget'); 
})
</script>
```

**LiQuickBootstrapper.js**

```
function submit_handler(formObj, widgetUri) {
    var submitObj = $(formObj).data('objClicked');
    var submitObjID = submitObj.attr('id');

    var formData = formObj.serialize()
        + '&'
        + encodeURI(submitObj.attr('id'))
        + '='
        + encodeURI(submitObj.attr('value'))
    ;

    $(formObj).fadeOut('2000');
    $(formObj).promise().done(function () {
        $.post(widgetUri, formData)
            .done(function (xData) {
                var newSubmitObj = $($.parseHTML(xData)).find("#" + submitObjID);
                var newForm = newSubmitObj.parents('form');
                formObj.html(newForm.html());
                $(formObj).fadeIn('2000');
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            });
        });
    return false;
}

function loadPage(widgetUri, containerIDLocal, containerIDRemote) {
    var containerObjLocal = $('#' + containerIDLocal);
    $(containerObjLocal).fadeOut('2000');
    $(containerObjLocal).promise().done(function () {
        $.post(widgetUri)
                .done(function (xData) {
                    var externalHTML = $.parseHTML(xData);
                    var containerObjRemote = $(externalHTML).filter('#' + containerIDRemote);
                    containerObjLocal.html(containerObjRemote.html());
                    var forms = containerObjLocal.children('form');
                    $(forms).submit(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        submit_handler($(event.currentTarget), widgetUri);
                    });
                    $(forms).click(function (event) {
                        $(this).data('objClicked', $(event.target));
                    });
                    $(forms).each(function () {
                        $(this).data('widgetUri', widgetUri);
                    });

                    __doPostBack = function (t, a) {
                        __myDoPostBack(t, a);
                    }
                    $(containerObjLocal).fadeIn('2000');
                })
                .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                });
    });
}

function __myDoPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    var submitObj = $("#" + eventTarget);
    var theForm = submitObj.parents('form:first');
    var submitObjID = submitObj.attr('id');
    var widgetUri = $(theForm[0]).data('widgetUri');

    $(theForm[0]).find(':hidden#__EVENTTARGET')[0].value = eventTarget;
    $(theForm[0]).find(':hidden#__EVENTARGUMENT')[0].value = eventArgument;

    var formData = theForm.serialize();

    $(theForm).fadeOut('2000');
    $(theForm).promise().done(function () {
        $.post(widgetUri, formData)
            .done(function (xData) {
                var newSubmitObj = $($.parseHTML(xData)).find("#" + submitObjID);
                var newForm = newSubmitObj.parents('form');
                theForm.html(newForm.html());
                $(theForm).fadeIn('2000');
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            });
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Iframe tag and bind **.aspx** page easily. It easy to use.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons to open the collapsible content.</p>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <iframe id="myFrame" src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778415/how-to-load-an-aspx-page-in-div-with-jquery-in-asp-net"></iframe>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <iframe id="myFrame" src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778415/how-to-load-an-aspx-page-in-div-with-jquery-in-asp-net"></iframe>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
 <iframe id="myFrame" src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778415/how-to-load-an-aspx-page-in-div-with-jquery-in-asp-net"></iframe>
</div>
```